# Using SQL like operator within a parameter in crystal report

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I need to use a like wildcard in the sql code for one of the paramenters in the crystal report.

I'm looking at stock symbols in SQL Server, my code works if I'm looking for the exact symbol but I need to search for similar symbols to catch any options or other versions of the stock.  i.e. not just GOOG, but like '%GOOG%'.  I can't find much online but I've tried using * instead of % and played around with the format but if I put in anything other than the exact symbol, my report comes up blank.

Original code:

```
where SYMB like '%GOOG%'
```

Crystal code:

```
where SYMB like {?symbol}
```

-----this will work but only if I type in the exact symbol that shows up, no deviations----

I tried adding '*"& {?symbol} & '*' - that didn't work either

When I run the code in sql server I get several lines that spit out trades for an option on GOOG, something like 'GOOG 160215C1200' but running the code through crystal spits out nothing because it is ONLY looking for 'GOOG' specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

SYMB like `["*GOOG*"]`  // will return values containing GOOG

OR

SYMB like `"*" & {?GOOG} & "*"`

Comment: I get an error when I try that, it says Invalid column name.  It seems like the issue is that  in the sql server code I would use '%GOOG%' but when trying to use 'GOOG' in the parameter there is no room for the wild card inside the string.  Is this even possible to do?

Comment: 'it says Invalid column name' - change field to SYMB

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
{SYMB} like {?sample}
```

this `{SYMB}` must be your field  without parenthesis like `SYMB` cannot be.

Answer (score 0):

For crystal syntax

```
SYMB like '*' + {?symbol} + '*'
```

If it is in the WHERE clause in a SQL command used for selecting data within Crystal then

```
WHERE SYMB LIKE '%' + {?symbol} + '%'
```